# How to specify the primary key number space for a postgres table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres table that contains data where the id has been set by the code that injected the data. So lets say the id is 0..49.

How can I instruct postgres to start with 50 on the id column for the next insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to happen it automatically (I mean, without the application doing that), you have to create a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE some_table_pk_seq START 50;
```

Then change the column to use this as a default:

```
ALTER TABLE some_table
ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('some_table_pk_seq'::regclass);
```

And that's it.  Remember that the default will be used only if you don't pass a value to the given column in your `INSERT` statements.

Comment: To do it after sequence (or serial) creation:  setval('some_table_pk_seq'::regclass, 50);

Comment: BTW, Postgres makes this process much easier with the new standard feature of *identity columns* via  [`GENERATED … AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createtable.html). See these posts: [*PostgreSQL 10 identity columns explained* by Peter Eisentraut](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/) and [*WAITING FOR POSTGRESQL 10 – IDENTITY COLUMNS* by Depesz](https://www.depesz.com/2017/04/10/waiting-for-postgresql-10-identity-columns/)